# apath statement for rapidminer

Tags: xpath, rapidminer

In rapid miner i am trying to take data using xpath from an xml page, i have tried a number of different statements but no success. Below is the data that im trying to retrieve, i want all the features from the un-ordered list.

```
enter code here

<div id="features">
<h3>Features:</h3>
<ul><li>Front  garden</li>
<li>Rear Large Shed</li>
<li>Superb condition and tastefully decorated</li>
<li>Energy Efficent with a B2 Ber rating</li>
<li>Gravel &amp; driveway</li>
</ul></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a sequence of strings there is the quick way:

```
//li/string()
```

And the specific way:

```
/div[@id='features']/ul/li/string()
```

Comment: I have tried both these statements but i get the same error reading back saying that specifiied xpath query is not valid, expected node-type. I have replaced string with text and the process will run but dosent return any values.Please help

Comment: @user2133572 can you provide a larger code snippet demonstrating what you're doing? The xpath is valid, so it's likely something in the caller function executing the xpath.

Comment: @user2133572 Put the code snippet in your question. It looks like you tried to edit my answer, and the changes were rejected by mods.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really specify how you need to pull this data or where it is going, but perhaps this will help:

I saved your example xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<div id="features"> 
<h3>Features:</h3>
<ul><li>Front  garden</li>
<li>Rear Large Shed</li>
<li>Superb condition and tastefully decorated</li>
<li>Energy Efficent with a B2 Ber rating</li>
<li>Gravel &amp; driveway</li>
</ul></div>
```

I then created the following RapidMiner process which pulls each list element as an individual attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="5.3.005">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="5.3.005" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="read_xml" compatibility="5.3.005" expanded="true" height="60" name="Read XML" width="90" x="112" y="165">
        <parameter key="file" value="path/to/Test.xml"/>
        <parameter key="xpath_for_examples" value="//h3"/>
        <enumeration key="xpaths_for_attributes">
          <parameter key="xpath_for_attribute" value="//li[1]/text()"/>
          <parameter key="xpath_for_attribute" value="//li[2]/text()"/>
          <parameter key="xpath_for_attribute" value="//li[3]/text()"/>
          <parameter key="xpath_for_attribute" value="//li[4]/text()"/>
          <parameter key="xpath_for_attribute" value="//li[5]/text()"/>
        </enumeration>
        <list key="namespaces"/>
        <parameter key="use_default_namespace" value="false"/>
        <list key="annotations"/>
        <list key="data_set_meta_data_information"/>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Read XML" from_port="output" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

I think the XPATH query you are looking for is "//li[n]/text()" where n is the number of the node from which you are trying to pull data. I hope this helps!